# Android ML Kit detection area

Tags: android, text-recognition, google-mlkit

I downloaded the ML Kit sample code for Android and i'm having a hard time to go about setting a limited detection area for the live camera detection (I'm only interested in text recognition, i got rid of everything else).

I need to limit the text recognition to only a part of the screen (say, a tiny rectangle or square in the center of the screen). Has anyone done such a workaround with ML kit?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [ML Kit Translate Showcase App](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/translate-showcase) which shows how to limit Text recognition to a specific section of the screen.